# IISExpress add path to website

Tags: iis

I have a website working fine on IIS express until I wanted to add a second one and have them both run off the same port number.  Now I can't figure out how to get the path right.  When I browse to the site after running iIS express it complains of a error:

Unrecognized configuration path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/RISWEB'

and IIS Express returns error 500.19

Here is my config.  When I set the path to be "/" it works, but when its something else it does not.  I would like to browse to http:// c65273/risweb and have my website show up.

```
        <site name="RISWEB" id="1834812154">
            <application path="/risweb" applicationPool="ConnectPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/risweb" physicalPath="C:\c2010\risweb\RISWEB" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:c65273" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Answer (score 11):

I hit a similar problem and was able to resolve it by doing the following:

1. Remove the configuration section for the site from my `applicationhost.config`
2. In Visual Studio go to the `Project Properties` > `Web` tab and then click `Create Virtual Directory` to have VS recreate the configuration section.

It then worked fine, the resulting configuration section will look something like this:

```
<site name="WebDemos-Site" id="5">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\rvesse\Documents\My Web Sites\WebDemos-Site" />
  </application>
  <application path="/demos">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\rvesse\Documents\mercurial\dotnetrdf\Samples\WebDemos" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64132:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

Note that VS generates an empty website for the root directory of the site

Comment: I did find out the same thing and can't figure out the reason. Apparently I am not the only one. The funny thing is the empty website is not generated by re-initialize iis express.

Comment: FYI to readers: `applicationhost.config` is located in `<solution folder>\.vs\config` which is a hidden folder. In the config xml file, the configuration section is under `configuration/system.applicationHost/sites`.